# How can I get PostgreSQL DBLink connections to work with JDBC?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc, kotlin, dblink

I'm not able to get named/unamed dblink connections to persist in my springboot "java" (actually kotlin) application. I am writing my code in kotlin. The code looks like this.

```
var result = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject<String>("SELECT dblink_connect('myTestConnectionName'," + myCloudServerConnectionString + ");")

println(result)  // prints "OK" meaning that it ran okay I believe.

var result2 = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject<String>("SELECT dblink_get_connections();")

println(result2) // prints "null" meaning there are no dblink connections.
```

I run the SQL manually in both PSQL and DBeaver and it works fine.  I will see the named connection when I run "dblink_get_connections" sql. It only doesn't work in my springboot application.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `dblink_connect()` requires a transaction.
Your code opens and immediately closes it. `dblink_get_connections` is executed in another transaction.
You can use `@Transactional` on your method to change this behavior.

Comment: Well I actually ended up not using the JDBCTemplate, and I used createStatement().executeQuery("my sql query") on the connection variable instead. It worked!